# Conformal map from upper-half disk to upper-half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem.

> Prove the function
> $$
> f(z)=-\frac12\left(z+\frac1z\right)
> $$
> is a conformal equivalence from $\mathbb D_+=\{z:\text{Im }z>0\text{ and }|z|<1\}$ to $\mathbb H_+=\{z:\text{Im }z>0\}$.

I've already shown that $f$ maps from $\mathbb D_+$ *into* $\mathbb H_+$. Now I want to show that there is an inverse that maps from $\mathbb H_+$ into $\mathbb D_+$. I believe that $g(z)=-z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is the desired inverse, though I am not sure how to show that $g$ maps any $z\in\mathbb H_+$ to a unique $g(z)\in\mathbb H_+$.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $h:\Omega\to \Bbb C$ be a holomorphic function defined on a **simply-connected** open subset $\Omega$ of $\Bbb C$ such that $h(z)\not=0$ for all $z\in \Omega$. Then, there is a holomorphic function, $H:\Omega\to \Bbb C$ such that $\big(H(z)\big)^2=h(z)$ for all $z\in \Bbb C$.

Here, $\Omega:=\Bbb H_+$ and $h:\Omega\ni z\longmapsto z^2-1\in \Bbb C$. So, define $$g(z)=-z+H(z)\text{ for all }z\in \Bbb H_+.$$

**Alternative way:** Show that every point of $\Bbb H_+$ can be written as $$-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(re^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}\bigg)=-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(r+\frac{1}{r}\bigg)\cos\theta-i\frac{1}{2}\bigg(r-\frac{1}{r}\bigg)\sin\theta\text{ for some }0<r<1,0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ Now, show $f$ is injective. So, open mapping theorem, etc. imply $f$ is bi-holomorphic.